# The click event of button isn't trigged in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have button in my page as you can  see here :

```
  <div class="buttonPossion">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnFinal" runat="server" Text="دانلود مقاله" CssClass="buttonBlue" OnClick="btnFinal_Click"/>
                </div>
```

The click event of this button is :

```
protected void btnFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count =
            dbcontext.tblJurorArticles.Where(i => i.articleid == articleId && i.jurorUsername == Session["juror"])
                     .Count();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../AdminPortal/DownloadArticleHandler.ashx?File=" +
                              obj.Return_filelocation_article(articleId.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("asda");
        }
    }
```

But when i click on the button it doesn't work .the important things is all my buttons in the page are disabled .

If the html code is needed ,i can include it in my  question.

The webconfig

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB-Conference-CivilConstruction" connectionString="Data Source=176.9.90.204,9992;Initial Catalog=DB-Conference-CivilConstruction;User ID=DB-Conference-CivilConstruction-user; password=123qweQWE@;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="DB-Conference-CivilConstruction" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.223.75;Initial Catalog=DB-Conference-CivilConstruction;User ID=DB-Conference-CivilConstruction-user; password=123qweQWE@;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->

  </connectionStrings>
   <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Best regards

Comment: _it doesn't work_ please explain. What doesn't work? The event is not triggered? There is no return value and you don't get your required redirect? The debugger could help you a lot, use it.

Comment: yes exactly the event not triggend

Comment: I put a new button but it doesn't work again

Comment: If the buttons are disabled, then did you check the CssClass and the Class on the Div tag if something disables the buttons?

Comment: The button's enable is true .let me check the css

Comment: I remove the css class but it doesn't work again

Comment: Set the break point in `btnFinal_Click` and debug if it doesn't call remove it and make a new event for `OnClick` of button.

Comment: Is there a lot of UI control in your page @EA ?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil yes exactly

Comment: @EA have a look @ my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: @EA Rebuild your solution, If you are using local IIS then reset IIS .

Comment: The html code is here:http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72127/discussion-between-e-a-and-med-amine-touil

Answer (score 0):

If your eventClick invoke a postback and Fire the page_Load function without moving to your click event hundler, and you are sure that OnClick attribute has the right event hundler name the you have to check your web.config

in this section

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="xxx" />
  </appSettings>
```

change it to

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
  </appSettings>
```

And if the "MaxHttpCollectionKeys" does not exist add it.

and change this config under the

```
<configuration> 
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
```

to

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

Comment: i added config file ,but i don't know which part should i add the code ?

Comment: Don't add a config file. In your existing web.config

under  the `<configuration>` tag

Comment: @EA Any progress there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72127/discussion-between-e-a-and-med-amine-touil).

Comment: the html code is available here :http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72127/discussion-between-e-a-and-med-amine-touil